# Excel iterative IFBLANK for a spreadsheet with missing data

Tags: excel

I want to find the rate of change of data in a spreadsheet but data is entered unevenly with blank entries and various time frames between data entries. I think I need to identify the previous nonblank cells, extract the data from that row and use that in the standard calculation.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17/10/2023 | 15 | 21 |  |
| 19/10/2023 | 15 | 22 |  |
|  |  |  |  |
| 24/10/2023 | 16 | 24 |  |
| 25/10/2023 |  |  |  |
| 27/10/2023 | 21 | 28 |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
| 2/11/2023 | 22 | 29 |  |
| 5/11/2023 | 24 | 32 |  |

Column D essentially wants to calculate the rate of change of the combined column B and C. I can't delete the empty rows as they contain data elsewhere on the sheet.

Currently the only solution I have come up with is to manually enter different formulae into each column D cell.

Comment: =FILTER(A:D,A:A<>"") to filter out blank rows, do calculations with output.